# AutoMapper: Map to collection from multiple source properties

Tags: c#, automapper

**UPDATE April 13th, 2018**: Automapper 6.1.0 supports unflattening by introducing `ReverseMap`. See release notes [here](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-6-1-0-released/)

I'm trying to use AutoMapper to unflatten an object.

I have a source as follows

```
public class Source
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Child1Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Child1Property2 {get;set;}
    public string Child2Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Child2Property2 {get;set;}
}
```

I want to map to this to destination

```
public class Destination
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
}
```

My mapping configuration

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static MapperConfiguration Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, /* What do I put here?*/))
                // I don't think this is correct
                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Child>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Property1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Child1Property1))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Property2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Child1Property2))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Property1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Child2Property1))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Property2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Child2Property2));

            });
        return config;
    }
}
```

Now when I test my code I get using `mapper.Map<List<Child>>(source)` I get a `AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.` Which make sense, since there isn't a mapping configured to a `List<Child>`. If I do `mapper.Map<Child>(source)`, I get a `Child` instance with all `null` values for the properties.

I'm unfortunately not in a position to modify the `Source` class.

Is this possible at all with AutoMapper? and if so how?

Comment: I see in the April 13th, 2018 that you include a link to `ReverseMap` which is supposed to help with unflattening, but I still don't know how it shows this scenario. Could whoever updated it include some sample code that would answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 options.  You can use a simple extension method to simplify the mapping or you can create a custom type converter.

```
public class ConvertSourceToDestination : ITypeConverter<Source, Destination>
{
    public Destination Convert(Source source, Destination destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = destination ?? new Destination();
        destination.Children = destination.Children ?? new List<Child>();
        destination.Children.Add(new Child() { Property1 = source.Child1Property1, Property2 = source.Child1Property2 });
        destination.Children.Add(new Child() { Property1 = source.Child2Property1, Property2 = source.Child2Property2 });
        destination.Name = source.Name;

        return destination;
    }
}

public static class SourceExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Child> Children(this Source source)
    {
        yield return new Child() { Property1 = source.Child1Property1, Property2 = source.Child1Property2 };
        yield return new Child() { Property1 = source.Child2Property1, Property2 = source.Child2Property2 };
    }

    public static MapperConfiguration CreateMapping()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children()));
            });

        return config;
    }

    public static MapperConfiguration CreateMapping2()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ConvertUsing(new ConvertSourceToDestination());

            });

        return config;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method on Source class to fetch the child list.
Then it's very easy to map .

Comment: Please provide a quick example

Comment: I think this answer is similar to @mikej's "extension method" solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom type converter, it may be better to use a [custom value resolver](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html) and leave the rest of the mapping to AutoMapper. In this case, it's not difficult to map `source.Name` to `destination.Name`, but imagine you had 10 other properties that AutoMapper could handle, or that you could use the default `opt.MapFrom` for.

Example custom value resolver:

```
public class SourceToDestinationChildResolver : IValueResolver<Source, Destination, List<Child>>
{
    public List<Child> Resolve(Source source, Destination destination, List<Child> member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = destination ?? new Destination();
        destination.Children = destination.Children ?? new List<Child>();
        destination.Children.Add(new Child() { Property1 = source.Child1Property1, Property2 = source.Child1Property2 });
        destination.Children.Add(new Child() { Property1 = source.Child2Property1, Property2 = source.Child2Property2 });
        // This is not needed then
        // destination.Name = source.Name;
        return destination.Children;
    }
}
```

Configuration to use resolver:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static MapperConfiguration Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom<SourceToDestinationChildResolver>())
            });
        return config;
    }
}
```

One thing that could help clarify my solution for myself is how is `List<Child> member` exactly used. Was not clear for me in the documentation, so someone please comment :)